# Combo box and Drop Down size

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, size

Is there a ways to keep the combo box in an MS Access form at a certain size, but have the drop down expand to a much larger size? Changing the column widths didnt work for me.

I'm basically trying to keep my combo box as small as possible and the drop down (once you click it) to be at the max size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The combo box has two properties in the format section that will accomplish this.  The `List Rows` controls how many items are listed and how tall the drop down will be before you have to start scrolling.

The `List Width` will control how wide your box is while the `Width` will control how large the combo box appears on your form.